# How can the validity of signatures in layer-2 transactions be proven in zk-rollup?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, cryptocurrency, blockchain

I have many questions about the details of using zk-SNARK technology in zk-rollup：

1. How can the validity of signatures in layer-2 transactions be proven in zk-rollup?
2. In zk-rollup, is a single large zero-knowledge proof circuit used to prove the validity of signatures for a batch of transactions, or is it separately proving the validity of each signature and then aggregating these proofs?
3. Are there any publicly available papers or tutorials that explain the details of proof signature validity in zk-rollup? Reading the zk-rollup project code is too challenging for me.